# How can I open my app using openUrl schema from app extension?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-app-extension

How can I open my app using `openUrl` schema from app extension? I have killed my app from background and I want open my app using app extension. Is it possible?

I have the following block of code, but it is not working.

```
[self.extensionContext openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl] completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        }];
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't open app from app extension. `UIApplication` isn't available for app extension https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.htmlhttps://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html. Here you will get which all `APIs` which are unavailable for app extension.